# Bash script to write all occurrences of application crash to a text file

Tags: linux, bash, logging, crash

I can't find how to structure my while loop properly to log to a text file all crashes of a given Linux application. I would like to get a prompt so I can input the application name and then a loop to watch the pid of the application. If the pid is null I wanted to log the timestamp in a text file and continue the loop. If still in null at the second iteration, don't log anything, keep monitoring until there are other crashes and other logs... and so on until the script stops with CTRL+C.

I've tried multiple variations of this script without luck. I think I need tips on how to think of a "loop structure" to achieve whatever goals...

```
read -p "What is the name of the application you want to monitor?" appname

pidofapp=`ps -elf | grep "$appname" | grep -v grep | awk '{print $4}'`
pidofappcheck=`ps -elf | grep "$appname" | grep -v grep | awk '{print $4}'`

while :
do
if [[ ! -z "$pidofappcheck" ]] ; then
        pidwasnull=true
pidofappcheck=`ps -elf | grep "$appname" | grep -v grep | awk '{print $4}'`
if [[ "$pidofapp" == "$pidofappcheck" ]] ; then
        printf "Still monitoring...\n"
        sleep 5
elif [[ "$pidwasnull" == true ]] ; then
        continue
fi
        echo "FAILURE: Crash occurred at: "$(date)" - Crashes will be logged in the monitoring tool directory under results.txt"
        date >> ./results.txt
fi
done
```

As it is right now, the script will echo:

`What is the name of the application you want to monitor?running
Still monitoring...
FAILURE: Crash occurred at: Wed May 22 01:44:53 EDT 2019 - Crashes will be logged in the monitoring tool directory under results.txt
Still monitoring...
FAILURE: Crash occurred at: Wed May 22 01:44:58 EDT 2019 - Crashes will be logged in the monitoring tool directory under results.txt`

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: First change your loop going wild: It won't sleep or finish when `pidofappcheck` is null or when `[[ "$pidofapp" == "$pidofappcheck" ]]` is false.

Comment: Reconsider `pidwasnull=true`. Once set it never becomes false and checking it has no use.

Comment: @Walter A - thanks for the time you took to review this. Indeed, pidwasnull variable is useless. I wanted to do this check in the loop to cover this case: pid is null at eval cause process hasnt restarded. I want to get only one entry for one occurrence in my log file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have been able to find a solution based on what @Walter A wrote. Here is what I've used. It's working as expected so far.

```
#!/bin/bash

read -rp "What is the name of the application you want to monitor?" appname
app_pid=$(pidof "$appname")

#echo "First PID of "$appname" is "$app_pid""

while : ; do
   lastpid=$(pidof "$appname")
   if [[ "${app_pid}" == "${lastpid}" ]] ; then
        printf "Still monitoring...\n"
   else
      crashtxt="Crashes will be logged in the monitoring tool directory under results.txt"
      echo "FAILURE: Crash occurred at: $(date) ${crashtxt}"
      date >> ./results.txt
      app_pid="$lastpid"
   fi
   sleep 5
done
```

So this script will basically check the PID of the given app until you CTRL+C. If the PID of the app changes while the script is running. It will output the timestamps of when it occurred in a "results.txt" file and it will keep checking it until you press CTRL+C. Therefore I am going to use this to log all crash occurrences of my apps. Thanks a lot @Walter A

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
#!/bin/bash
getpidofapp() {
   # pid=$(ps -elf | grep "$1" | grep -v grep | awk '{print $4}' | head -1)
   pid=$(pgrep "$1" | head -1)
   test -n "${pid}" || { echo "Is ${appname} running?"; exit 1; } 
}

read -rp "What is the name of the application you want to monitor?" appname
app_pid=$(getpidofapp "${appname}")

while : ; do
   lastpid=$(getpidofapp "${appname}")
   if [[ "${app_pid}" == "${lastpid}" ]] ; then
        printf "Still monitoring...\n"
   else
      crashtxt="Crashes will be logged in the monitoring tool directory under results.txt"
      echo "FAILURE: Crash occurred at: $(date) ${crashtxt}"
      date >> ./results.txt
   fi
   sleep 5
done
```

Comment: hi thanks for your answer. i didnt try it yet but im thinking of this case; what if the app gets killed, pid is now null, another check is made through next iteration, the app hasnt restarded yet, therefore, $app_pid wont == $lastpid cause it still evaluates to false and it will write another line in the results.txt each time the loop starts nah?

Comment: When app_pid==null, `getpidofapp()` will cause an `exit 1`. When you want tochange this behaviour, you can make a loop inside the `getpidofapp()` function.
(including a sleep, logging and max retries?)

Comment: got it. very good idea. thanks a lot for the time you took to help me. will try this as soon as possible and update the post accordingly.